# How are low-quality answers detected?

Tags: discussion, review

In the sidebar of [the review page](https://askubuntu.com/review) it said:

> These are automatically detected low quality posts on Ask Ubuntu.

How are those detected?

Comment: This is detailed in this meta.SO post:

- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer

Comment: @JorgeCastro that should be an answer.

Comment: The site autoconverted it to a comment!

Comment: @EmersonHsieh What about low quality questions? Thats rife on lots of stackexchange websites now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We *need* this out of the unanswered queue.

> This is detailed in this meta.SO post: - [meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/72523/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer)

Jorge Castro Jun 19 at 4:01